# Is it possible to get copied file from explorer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, chat

I have worked on a chat feature where the requirement is to get copied images on paste them from file explorer (like skype desktop). e.g I CTRL+C an image file then CTRL+V on Chat textarea.
But I get images only from the clipboard.
From file explorer, it is not working.
Here is a demo screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try some of those https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard - either the new (and still somewhat experimental) *navigator.clipboard* api or the old *document.execCommand* function.

Comment: I used a clipboard to get copied to the clipboard image but from file explorer, is there any way?

Comment: When CTRL-C a file in the explorer and CTRL-V in the browser, the file is in the clipboard all the same, but presumably stored in a different way.

Comment: Yeah, I actually want to know this different way. I couldn't find where this copied file was stored. Can you please give me an idea?